# Symfony 4 : PostgreSQL : SCRAM authentifcation problem?

Tags: postgresql, symfony4

I have this error : "pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above." when I try to generate entity for a database already existing. How can I solve it ?

I'm using Pg12